# mongoid validates array has at least 1 element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, mongoid

We have

```
class Event
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :categories, type: Array, default: []
end
```

How to validate an event object to have at least 1 element in categories? Should I use custom validator? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

```
class Event
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :categories, type: Array, default: []

  validates :categories, length: { minimum: 1 }
end
```

Should do the trick (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#length)

Comment: Has anyone tested the solution given in this answer?

Comment: I did test it. This actually works. You should mark this answer as correct **Yudho**. Thanks **nort**.